# Ajax call inside the command column scrolls up entire Kendo Grid

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In the command column, I have a buttons with an onClick ajax requests. After the ajax request data inside the grid is scrolled to top.

I have included e.preventDefault(); but it works only for browser window not inside the grid.

```
command: [
{
    name: "reset",
    text: " ",
    className: "btn btn-sm btn-warning fas fa-undo",
    click: function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
       var data = this.dataItem(tr);
       data.set("Decision", "testtest");
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("Waiting", "Absence", data.Register_ID),
           type: "POST"           
       });
    },
}]
```

How can I prevent it to scroll to top?

Comment: A `return false` at the end of the function may do the trick.

Comment: it did not help :(

Comment: I just realized: The line with the uri is missing the closing ' right before the comma.

Comment: Yes, I just missed it when was editing code here for post

Comment: Library update resolved that issue.